# Get data-bind value of button in html table

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal

How get data-bind value in ViewsModel from Button in html table when  click ?

Please help me?

Views:

```
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Id
            </th>
            <th>
                Naziv
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: customers">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: Id_dobavljaca">

            </td>
            <td data-bind="text: NazivDobavljaca">

            </td>
             <td>
                <button data-bind="click: edit, value: Id_dobavljaca">
                    Edit</button>
                <button >
                    Test</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

ViewModel:

```
define(function (require) {

    var app = require('durandal/app'), system = require('durandal/system'),
     ko = require('knockout');

    return {

        customers: ko.observableArray([]),

        activate: prikazi

    }




});



function prikazi() {

    var system = require('durandal/system');

    var that = this;
    system.log('krenu po podatke');


    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/Durandal/VratiDobavljace',

        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            that.customers(data);
        },
        error: function (jq, st, error) {
            alert(error);
        }



    });

    system.log('doneo podatke');


    edit = function edit1(Id_dobavljaca) {

        var system = require('durandal/system');

        alert(Id_dobavljaca);


        var router = require('plugins/router');
        router.navigate('treci/' + 123456);

    };




    return that.customers
}
```

I want to pass value (  Id_dobavljaca )in ViewsModels when click button in html table..

Thanks alot!

Martin

Comment: what? i do not understand your question i need to see your view model? and for you to explain a little better what is not working?

Comment: Second that, the question is really rather hard to understand. Please consider editing your question: use the preview to at least format the code properly. In addition it would help if you trim the code to a *minimal* scenario, and tell us what you've tried / why your solutions don't work.

Answer (score 1):

In *DurandalJS*, the object that you return from your *requirejs* module that is your view model is the object bound to the view. The *activate* function will be called when *DurandalJS* composes your view and view model, you can read more [here](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-Composition.html).

In your current implementation the `observableArray` *customers* is a property on your view model and can be bound to your view, which is great and I assume working.

However, from looking at your current implementation you have not exposed the `edit` function on your view model which means it cannot be bound to the UI and used.

I have refactored your view model:

```
define(function(require) {

    var app = require('durandal/app'),
        system = require('durandal/system'),
        router = require('plugins/router'),
        ko = require('knockout');

    var customers = ko.observableArray([]);

    return {
        customers: customers,
        edit: function(context) {
            alert(context.Id_dobavljaca);
            router.navigate('treci/' + context.Id_dobavljaca);

        },

        activate: function() {
            system.log('krenu po podatke');

            return $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '/Durandal/VratiDobavljace',
                    dataType: "json"
                })
                .done(function(data) { customers(data); })
                .fail(function(jq, st, error) { alert(error); })
                .always(function() { system.log('doneo podatke'); });
        }

    }

});
```

This refactoring exposes the `customers` *observableArray* property and the `edit` function. The activate function also loads your data and returns the promise back to the *DurandalJS* composition life cycle.

Now, you will notice that the edit function takes an argument called `context`, this is a *knockoutjs* thing. When a function is bound to the `click` binding the first argument passed to the function is the *binding context*, you can read more [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html).

Using this refactored view model, in your markup you want to bind your *edit* button to the `edit` function on the `$root` context, which is your view model.

```
<td>
   <button data-bind="click: $root.edit">Edit</button>
   <button>Test</button>
</td>
```

Hopefully, the snippet below can demonstrate this explanation.

```js
var example1 = {
  customers: ko.observableArray([{
    Id_dobavljaca: 123,
    NazivDobavljaca: 'Martin',
    edit: function(context) {
      alert('Id_dobavljaca: ' + this.Id_dobavljaca);
      alert('Id_dobavljaca: ' + context.Id_dobavljaca);
    }
  }, {
    Id_dobavljaca: 321,
    NazivDobavljaca: 'Anish',
    edit: function(context) {
      alert('Id_dobavljaca: ' + this.Id_dobavljaca);
      alert('Id_dobavljaca: ' + context.Id_dobavljaca);
    }
  }, ])

}

ko.applyBindings(example1, $('#example1')[0]);

var example2 = {
  customers: ko.observableArray([{
    Id_dobavljaca: 123,
    NazivDobavljaca: 'Martin'
  }, {
    Id_dobavljaca: 321,
    NazivDobavljaca: 'Anish'
  }, ]),
  edit: function(context) {
    alert('Id_dobavljaca: ' + context.Id_dobavljaca);
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(example2, $('#example2')[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<p>Edit function is a property on each customer object<p>
<table id="example1" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Id
      </th>
      <th>
        Naziv
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: customers">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: Id_dobavljaca">

      </td>
      <td data-bind="text: NazivDobavljaca">

      </td>
      <td>
        <button data-bind="click: edit">
          Edit</button>
        <button>
          Test</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<p>Edit function is a property on the view model<p>
<table id="example2" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Id
      </th>
      <th>
        Naziv
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: customers">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: Id_dobavljaca">

      </td>
      <td data-bind="text: NazivDobavljaca">

      </td>
      <td>
        <button data-bind="click: $root.edit">
          Edit</button>
        <button>
          Test</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: this part.... .done(function () { customers(data); }) .....get error ...the "data" is not defied..please help me...

Comment: I've updated my answer, I forgot to specify the argmument `done(function (data) { customers(data); })`

Comment: You have helped me a lot!! Thanks!!

Comment: No problem buddy, glad I could help : )